# Why MariaDB refuses to create a simple table with error [42000][1064]?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, create-table

I just want to know how to fix this, or why MariaDB server keeps me returning an error. I just install the database, create a user, a new schema, I'm pointing to that database with `use database testing;` and I'm ready to create a simple table on a database with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    ID          NUMBER(4)    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME        VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    DEPTO       VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

The user in the database I'm using has granted all privileges. But MariaDB returns:

```
[42000][1064] (conn=14) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)' at line 2
Query is: CREATE TABLE USERS (
ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
java thread: RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types are from Oracle, and you could set the [SQL_MODE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modeoracle-from-mariadb-103/) to accept that syntax:

> In MariaDB 10.3 and later, setting the sql_mode system variable to Oracle allows the server to understand a subset of Oracle's PL/SQL language. For example:

```
SET SQL_MODE='ORACLE';

CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    ID          NUMBER(4)    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME        VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    DEPTO       VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Keep in mind that NUMBER and VARCHAR2 are synonyms:

```
+-------------+-----------------+
| Oracle type | MariaDB synonym |
+-------------+-----------------+
| VARCHAR2    | VARCHAR         |
| NUMBER      | DECIMAL         |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=04730b54def405a0c297de5cfc732198)**

Comment: That's the solution I need for the excercise I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using Oracle syntax in a MySQL database. Some adaptations are needed:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
    ID          INT    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DEPTO       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Namely:

- `VARCHAR2(n)` is specific to Oracle; MySQL (and most other databases) have `VARCHAR(n)`
- There is no `NUMBER(n)` datatype in MySQL either; there is `NUMERIC(n, m)`, which is a fixed-point number, but you probably want `INT` here anyway